# GCC keeps on showing "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find" even when -L path is specified

Tags: gcc, static-libraries

I am trying to compile `main.c` with a static library and header files on an Ubuntu server using gcc and ssh using Terminal on Mac. I uploaded the library file and specified it with -L option and specified the header files using the -I option.

I tried using:

```
gcc main.c -L/Libraries/lib/libRNA.a -lRNA  -ILibraries/include/ViennaRNA
```

It comes out with:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRNA
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

`-L` expects a directory as argument. You're passing the name of the library.

Just do:

```
gcc main.c -L/Libraries/lib -lRNA -ILibraries/include/ViennaRNA
```

or link with the absolute path of the `.a` file directly:

```
gcc main.c /Libraries/lib/libRNA.a -ILibraries/include/ViennaRNA
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it said:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRNA
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I tried the second one and it said:
gcc: error: /Libraries/lib/libRNA.a: No such file or directory

Comment: I changed the directory and it works, thanks. However it says "file not recognized: File format not recognized". probably the .a file is created using the "make" command in my Mac, which is incompatible with ubuntu

Comment: Yes you have to rebuild the .a file on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` option specifies a *directory* where the library file is.

Answer (score 0):

The `-L` option to  `gcc` (which gets actually passed to `ld`) is expecting a *directory* (in which further `-l` options are seeked).

The `-I` option is expecting a directory containing included header files.

So you want

```
 gcc -Wall -g main.c -L/Libraries/lib/ -lRNA -ILibraries/include/ViennaRNA
```

You really want all warnings (`-Wall`) and debug information (`-g`) to be able to use the `gdb` debugger.